# how to apply shift to left of 16 in assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have wrote this code of assembly 8086 :

```
data segment
   
          a dw 0a25h
          b dw 0a42h
          c dd ?
          d dd ?                  
data ends
code segment 
   assume ds:data, cs:code,ss:begin 
     begin:    
     
   mov ax,data 
   mov ds,ax
       
     mov ax,a
     mov bx,b   
     mul bx
     mov d,ax 
     mov c,dx 
     shl c, 16
```

the probleme is that the instruction **SHL** doesn't work in if i put 16 as second parameter

Comment: What do you expect it to do with a 16 bit register?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with “doesn't work.”

Comment: 16 bits is 2 bytes / 1 word. Just shuffle your data as needed. Note the result of `mul bx` has the high word in `dx` but x86 is little endian so you likely just want `mov c, ax` and `mov d, dx`. Also you want both of those defined with `dw`.

Comment: For general dword shifts on 8086, you would write a loop of `shl low, 1 / rcl high, 1`, shifting through the carry flag.  But of course, as @Jester says, with shifts that are a multiple of 8 bits, move bytes or words around instead.

Comment: @possum I want this dd number : `00000068` to become like that `00680000`

Comment: The 8086 instruction set doesn't seem to have a `mem,immed8` operation https://pcpatil.files.wordpress.com/2018/01/80x86_instruction_set_alphabetcal.pdf
Try a `mov cl,16    shl c, cl`